# Differences between Dein and Deine

Tags: vocabulary

I study German. I don't know when to write *dein* or *deine*. For example: *Dein Buch* and *Deine Sporttasche*.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works. Your question boils down to ‘how do I recognise a noun’s gender?’

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dein is a Possesivartikel. It depends on what you are talking about.

For the case Nominativ (what you're talking about) there are the following rules:

- **Maskulinum** (der) -> *dein*
- **Femininum** (die) -> *deine*
- **Neutrum** (das) -> *dein*
- **Plural** (die) -> *deine*

So regarding your examples:

> Das Buch (**Neutrum**) -> *Dein* Buch
>
> Die Sporttasche (**Femininum**) -> *Deine* Sporttasche

Comment: From Duolingo `Mein Bruder liebt deinen Opa`. Why `deinen` is used here? It should be dein or deine (respectfully)